# EF7 Navigation property with interface

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Is **Entity Framework 7** support Navigation property using interface type?
I can find any answer to this on Google

`ICollection<IMyInterface> ObjectCollection { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, EF only knows models which are classes. Defining a collection of interfaces like you do is impossible. However, what you can do is write extension methods to query on which have interface constraints. For example:

```
IMyInterface { int Id {get; set;}}

public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> q, int id) where T: IMyInterface
{
   return q.Where(q.Id == id);
}
```

Here T is a model which has to implement `IMyInterface`.

Comment: I know that it is not possible with EF6, but is this true even with EF7?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible, what are you trying to do actually?

Comment: I'm trying to separate my object in a way that I could end up with an assembly that contain only interface. So I could use those interface every where in may app. And therefor easily implement Mock object for testing purpopse

Comment: I write my business logic so that it only defines in an interface what repository calls it needs and what state it can persist. This solves the issue - your EF model is then an implementation of that interface. If you're interested let me know and I'll work it out in an Answer. It also helps you to keep collections read only if you want to limit interaction to your own public methods only. As far as I know, what you want is indeed not possible..